Prepend URLs with directory if a language is selected (Polylang Synced Pages)
I'm using Polylang on a WordPress page where there are multiple languages and translated pages.
There are two languages who are very similar (90% the same) but a few pages are different, therefore I've synced most of the pages.
Syncing Pages
In Polylang you can sync pages, meaning that the complete content, all the changes are being instantly synced to the translation.
Therefore when I link to website.com/materials the translated page will be edited so it links to website.com/fr/materials but the synced page should go to website.com/en/materials instead of website.com/materials.
Otherwise I would need to translate all the pages just to be able to edit the links.
That means it also syncs the links which then direct to the origin language and the therefore displaying the content in that origin language. I need to be able to add the language directory in front of every URL so the user stays on that language page.
I can get the the directory with the following code:
$language = pll_current_language('slug');
I've tried it with the following code but the directory get's ignored:
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_page_based_on_language' );

function rewrite_page_based_on_language() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . $language . '/%pagename%';
}


I don't understand what means "syncing links". edit your question to add more details and an example.

@mmm I added more context to the syncing but. Hope that helps
